# Nexus index loses artifact after deploy

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-indexer

I have a nexus repo (v2.1.2) where I deploy osgi bundles created with the maven-bundle-plugin. By default, the nexus index doesn't include packages of type bundle, so if i do a search for a bundle, I only get a reference to the pom, not the bundle (jar). 
However, following this [entry](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21566122-why-don-t-artifacts-with-custom-packaging-types-show-up-in-search-results), I managed to make it work correctly. Here is what I added to `/usr/local/sonatype-work/nexus/conf/packaging2extension-mapping.properties`

```
bundle=jar
```

If after the change I do a rebuild index as suggested in the article, now the index contains the bundles. However, my problem is that when i redeploy a new snapshot of one of the bundles, it disappears from the index. The only way to get it back is by recreating the index one more time. Obviously at this point the whole workflow is unusable: i can't manually recreate the index after every deploy.

Is this a known issue? a bug? a misconfiguration?
Any ideas how to fix it?
I'm using the REST api to do queries so losing the artifacts from the index is pretty bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug
There was a ticket opened for it
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-5525